# How to pass a list array parameter to a web service in c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I am attempting to consume a web service from BMC Remedy 7.6.04 that creates a Remedy Incident. Several of the parameters are arrays from which you choose a value to send back to the web service such as Status. I'm getting the following error when I choose a StatusType, UrgencyType and ImpactType.Here is the error for Status Type:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Client.RemedyInc.StatusType' to
>   'Client.RemedyInc.StatusType[]'

Status is enumerated in the reference.cs as follows:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS")]
public enum StatusType {        
    /// <remarks/>
    New,        
    /// <remarks/>
    Assigned,        
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("In Progress")]
    InProgress,        
    /// <remarks/>
    Pending,        
    /// <remarks/>
    Resolved,        
    /// <remarks/>
    Closed,        
    /// <remarks/>
    Cancelled,
}
```

AND:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS", Order=32)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Status")]
public StatusType[] Status;
```

Here is a sample of my code:

```
protected void ToRemedy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemedyInc.AuthenticationInfo AuthInfo = new RemedyInc.AuthenticationInfo();
            AuthInfo.userName = "User";
            AuthInfo.password = "Password";

            RemedyInc.HelpDesk_Submit_ServiceRequest RemTicket = new RemedyInc.HelpDesk_Submit_ServiceRequest();

            RemTicket.AuthenticationInfo = AuthInfo;

            RemTicket.Summary = "This is a web service Test";
            RemTicket.Last_Name = "LName";
            RemTicket.First_Name = "FName";
            RemTicket.Service_Type = RemedyInc.Service_TypeType.UserServiceRequest;
            RemTicket.Reported_Source = RemedyInc.Reported_SourceType.SelfService;

            RemTicket.Status = RemedyInc.StatusType.New;
            RemTicket.Urgency = RemedyInc.UrgencyType.Item4Low;
            RemTicket.Impact = RemedyInc.ImpactType.Item4MinorLocalized;

            RemTicket.Notes = "This is a web service test";
            RemTicket.TemplateID = "AGGAAHHLITMRAAMBGOJWBIN45LBV62";
            RemTicket.Action = "CREATE";

        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Ken

Answer (score 0):

Should your `Status` be declared as an array? That seems to be what the exception is in that you can't assign the `StatusType` to type `StatusType[]`

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS", Order=32)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Status")]
public StatusType Status; // Declared as StatusType instead of StatusType[]
```

And if the declaration is correct, then perhaps you just need your calling code to assign the New value as an array.

```
RemTicket.Status = new StatusType[] { RemedyInc.StatusType.New };
```